# Subtype in console overrides existing subtab

Tags: console, consoleintegrationtoolkit

I have the clone button on case(overriden the standard clone button) which opens a cloned case as a subtab in console.However when the clone button is clicked on the newly created case a new subtab does not open. Instead the first cloned subtab is overriden.

Detail | CaseNum1 | CaseNum2

That is if the clone button is clicked on CaseNum1 , CaseNum2 is opened in new subtab. But if clone button on CaseNum2 is opened then CaseNum2 is overriden by CaseNum and so on.

Detail | CaseNum1 | CaseNum3(CaseNum2 is overriden)

JS:

```
function start(){
sforce.console.getEnclosingPrimaryTabId(openSubtab);
} 
var openSubtab = function openSubtab(result){   
var primaryTabId = result.id;
sforce.console.openSubtab(primaryTabId,'/'+caseid,true,caseNum,null,,,);
}
```

The standard Case clone button is overriden by the Page : OverrideCaseVF from where the opensubTab logic is called after cloning the case.

OverrideCaseVF:

```
<apex:actionFunction oncomplete="start();" name="clone" action="{!duplicateCase}"/>
```

Comment: Where do you have the `openSubtab` code? its hard to visualize the problem, how to replicate it

Comment: `apex:actionFunction` does not have rerender tag

Comment: It does not help. I have tried putting rerender on the entire form and even the page.